# python SSL error when running python ez_setup.py

Tags: python-2.7

When I run `python ez_setup.py` , I get the following SSL Error.

> urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

I am running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.10. What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The complete ssl error is like below :                                                     urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>

Comment: please use "edit" to include the error into the question.

Comment: I am Also getting same error but on redhat

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error even when running `python ez_setup.py --insecure` on a CentOS 5.7 server with Python 2.7.12. Even though I couldn't find the root cause for the error I was able to work around it. ez_setup.py supports the following command line arguments:

```
# python ez_setup.py --help
Usage: ez_setup.py [options]

Options:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --user               install in user site package
  --download-base=URL  alternative URL from where to download the setuptools
                       package
  --insecure           Use internal, non-validating downloader
  --version=VERSION    Specify which version to download
  --to-dir=TO_DIR      Directory to save (and re-use) package
```

I knew the version I wanted to install and specified it on the command line:

```
# python ez_setup.py --insecure --version=25.2.0
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-25.2.0.zip
...
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

The download still failed but it printed out the download URL. Next download the package with `wget` or `curl` and run the install script with `--to-dir` command line parameter.

```
# wget --insecure https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-25.2.0.zip
# python ez_setup.py --insecure --version=25.2.0 --to-dir=.
```

Setuptools should now have been installed.